# Using "Build Xcode Project.action" in automator

Tags: xcode, bash, xcodebuild, automator

I successfully used `xcodebuild` to build my project in a bash script. I'm trying to port my script into automator, so I'm trying to take benefit using the "Build Xcode Project.action"

In the bash script, I move to folder where project is and run the `xcodebuild`. How can i achieve the same result into automator? I would like to set a variable named `projectFolder` in previous steps and pass this to the build action.

I know that i can put the whole build fragment of my script as shell script action of the automation, but this is not what i want.

Comment: Hii I am stuck in similar thing.I want to edit some parameters in info.plist before generating a build. Can you help me ???

Comment: After almost a year, I'm still using the bash script. With that script I can edit plist properties, see my other question on the argument: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970218/how-can-i-use-plistbuddy-to-access-an-element-of-preferencesspecified-by-its-pro